# Rebind events in jsf after Ajax update (PrimeFaces and Snap.svg)

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, snap.svg

I have created a custom component with Snap.svg.js that draws graphic on svg canvas. It works perfect but I have problem with events. I bind events such:

```
var draughts = snap.selectAll("circle[fill~='" + draughtMineColor + "']");
draughts.forEach(function (draught) {
    draught.unhover();
    draught.hover(function () {
        draught.animate({r: draughtRadius + 2}, 100, snap.easeIn);
    }, function () {
        draught.animate({r: draughtRadius}, 100, snap.easeIn);
    });
});
```

It works and draughts (circles) grows up on hover in and returns back on hover out. But when I click on draught I call listener that updates it and some squares like this:

```
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    if (event.getTarget() instanceof Draught) {
        Draught clicked = (Draught) event.getTarget();
        if (prevClicked != null) {
            prevClicked.updateShape();
        }
        clicked.setFill("red");
        board.resetDeskDrawing();
        board.highlightAllowedMoves(clicked);
        prevClicked = clicked;
    } else if (event.getTarget() instanceof Square) {
        Square square = (Square) event.getTarget();
        board.moveDraught(prevClicked, square);
    }
}
```

And JSF:

```
<h:form prependId="false">
    <p:remoteCommand name="updateCanvas" update="canvas" oncomplete="updatePlay();"/>
    <snap:svg id="canvas" value="#{playView.model}" style="height: 600px; width: 600px;">
        <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{playView.onClick}"
                oncomplete="updateCanvas();"/>
    </snap:svg>
</h:form>
```

But after click hover stops working. Any ideas?

Comment: Hover is function from Snap.svg library it is http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Element.hover

Comment: Then it is most likely caused by Snap.svg only adding eventhandlers on the document ready event. If you can find out how to add thsese event handlers again (the source is open, find the function) you can call that function in ajax oncomplete

Comment: The first snippet is from updatePlay() function that is called in remote command updateCanvas() on event update oncomplete (last snippet). And it calls hover event handler.

Comment: Sorry no idea why I missed that. The updatePlay() is fired I assume? And why do you do a two step update? Ajax->RemoteCommand. Can't you combine the two in one?

Comment: Yes, it is fired on update. Because I thought it will be called after update action in right direction Ajax then custom js function also I tried to do like this <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{playView.onClick}" update="canvas" oncomplete="upadtePlay();"/> but anywhere function updatePlay was called but events don't fired.

Comment: When you debug the js,does draughts have a value?

Comment: I've recorded the video. Please, watch it may be, it helps you understand https://youtu.be/0mW2jMnbm3g

Comment: Oh I understand the issue,was just trying to 'debug'. If they are populated, I have no clue

Comment: Please creste an answer yourself then preferably with the working code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in improperly initiated snap.svg. It should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    updatePlay();
});

updatePlay = function () {
    **snap = Snap("#canvas");**

    var draughts = snap.selectAll("circle[fill~='" + draughtMineColor + "']");
    console.log(draughts);
    draughts.forEach(function (draught) {
        draught.unhover();
        draught.hover(function () {
            draught.animate({r: draughtRadius + 10}, 100, snap.easeIn);
        }, function () {
            draught.animate({r: draughtRadius}, 100, snap.easeIn);
        }, draught);
    });
};
```